# Connect to SQL Server in different domain programmatically with ONLY Windows credentials

Tags: .net, sql-server, postman

***Note: I want to connect only via WINDOWS Credentials.*** I have a SQL Server database e.g. `xyz.domain1.net` which can connect via `domain1\<myId>` but my Windows credentials is different domain i.e. `domain2\<myId>`.

I am able to connect to the database server from my machine via SSMS by running the command `runas /netonly /user:'domain1\<myId>' "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe`, but I also want to connect from .NET code and executing from POSTMAN. Is there any way to do this ?

My appsetting.json is as below

```
ConnectionStrings: {

"SiteDbConnection": "Server=xyz.domain1.net; Database=someDB; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"}
```

**Is it even *`POSSIBLE`* to achieve ?**

Comment: Depends on the .net code, console app? If it is a console app, you can setup your connection string to use the credentials you ran the app with, and use the same runas command for your executable.

Comment: its a console. But i do not have credentials, I need to connect it via windows credentials only. which seems to be possible for SSMS tool but not when ran with postman ?

Comment: What happens when youuse RunAs with postman? Is postman connecting to the SQL Server?

Comment: even after running postman with RunAs command "runas /netonly /user:domain1\<myid> "C:\Users\myid\AppData\Local\Postman\Postman.exe"", it still takes domain2 and not domain1. whereas SSMS changes to domain2.

Comment: What makes you think "it still takes domain2" ? Is there some kind of feedback from postman?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, when running via POSTMAN is get that feedback.

Comment: What does _is get that feedback._ mean? can you post the message you are seeing?

Comment: i get this message like "ClassName": "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
"Message": "Login failed for user 'domain1\\userName'.",